# MCrypt is missing from your system. OS Yosemite

Tags: php, macos, laravel

So at work, I've been tasked to learn and start to use some Laravel, so I've been following the documentation and some tutorials on Youtube, but I cannot seem to get it working. I am using composer and MAMP to install Laravel. When I use the command (in the terminal) "composer create-project laravel/laravel TestLaravel" while in htdocs. It quickly comes up with this error:

```
➜  htdocs  composer create-project laravel/laravel TestLaravel
Installing laravel/laravel (v5.0.1)
  - Installing laravel/laravel (v5.0.1)
    Loading from cache

Created project in TestLaravel
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - laravel/framework v5.0.5 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.0.4 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.0.3 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.0.2 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.0.1 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.0.0 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - Installation request for laravel/framework 5.0.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.0.0, v5.0.1, v5.0.2, v5.0.3, v5.0.4, v5.0.5].
```

I was wondering if anyone would have a solution to this problem for me.

Thank you.

Joshua Johnson

Comment: would homestead be an option for you? it is the officially recommended dev-env see https://laracasts.com/lessons/say-hello-to-laravel-homestead-two

Comment: Other than Homestead, Homebrew (no relation - http://brew.sh/) is a good way of installing stuff like PHP on OSX. `brew install php56 php56-mcrypt` would do the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way that I got around this was to install [Homestead](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/homestead) and make sure to log in to the Homestead Virtual Machine before running any commands. MCrypt is not installed on your local machine, but it is in Homestead.

Comment: Thank you, I'm going to give this a go now, hopefully this works.

Comment: Good luck Josh! Homestead is really slick once you get it up and running. Remember to do all your `composer` and `artisan` commands while you are logged in to homestead with `homestead ssh`

Answer (score 6):

## Mac OS X Yosemite

> **the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system**

I fixed this error by running the following commands in my Terminal :

```
brew update
brew upgrade
brew tap homebrew/dupes
brew tap josegonzalez/homebrew-php
brew install php54-mcrypt
```

Comment: This worked for me on El Capitan (upgraded from Yosemite).

Comment: The 4th step just resulted in a bunch of errors on my OSX Yosemite :
Error: Invalid formula: /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/josegonzalez/homebrew-php/Formula/arcanist.rb
Formulae found in multiple taps: 
 * homebrew/php/php53
 * josegonzalez/php/php53

Please use the fully-qualified name e.g. homebrew/php/php53 to refer the formula.
Error: Invalid formula: /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/josegonzalez/homebrew-php/Formula/behat.rb
Formulae found in multiple taps: 
 * homebrew/php/php53
 * josegonzalez/php/php53
and so on ...

Answer (score 3):

Mostly this problem comes when your MAMP PHP Version not match with command version php. Please have a look in terminal by type php -v then it will show version like php 5.5.*

The problem is you have to set your MAMP PHP Path in `~/.bash_profile` like this :

```
sudo nano ~/.bash_profile

PATH="/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.7/bin:$PATH"
```

That's all, or install mcrypt lib if you want to use your default system php.

Comment: this helped with Magento 2.x and MAMP. Couldn't run any Magento commands before this. Thank you. Also, be sure to change the "php5.6.7" above to a version you have installed in MAMP.

Answer (score 0):

There's a PHP extension named `mcrypt` that's often not distributed with stock PHP packages.  The `mcrypt` extension is the defacto standard PHP extension for encryption and hashing functionality.  Laravel uses mcrypt.

The built in PHP on OS X does not come with `mcrypt` installed.  This means you either need to

1. Build and install the `mcrypt` extension yourself for OS X's built in PHP
2. Use homebrew to build and install PHP with mycrypt
3. Use a "pre-compiled for OS X" PHP package.
4. Use a vagrant virtual machine to run your development stack

I usually chose the third option, and use the [lipp.ch](http://php-osx.liip.ch/) package.  This is a long running project, and has it's roots in the old entropy.ch packages managed by Marc Liyanage from even further back.

Comment: Thank you, I'll keep that in mind. For now, I'm going to try it through Homestead :)