# Error composer update php laravel? ("laravel/framework" : "~5.0")

Tags: php, mysql, macos, laravel

I try to run on OSX:

**$ composer update**

*Error:*

> laravel/framework v5.0.9 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP
>   extension mcrypt is missing from your system.

.....

Then I try to get ext-mcrypt by:

**$ sudo php5enmod mcrypt**

[From this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/460837/mcrypt-extension-is-missing-in-14-04-server-for-mysql)

> *Error:* php5enmod: command not found.

Then I fix it by:

**$ brew install php5-mcrypt.**

*Error:* No available formula for php5-mcrypt.

So, t try:

- **$ brew install php54-mcrypt --without-homebrew-php** (*Error:* Unsupported PHP API Version).
- **$ brew doctor**
- **$ brew install php5-mcrypt.**

[From this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14357107/installing-mcrypt-on-osx-10-8-2-php-5-3-15-with-homebrew)

But it not work for me.

Comment: http://aryo.lecture.ub.ac.id/easy-install-php-mcrypt-extension-on-ubuntu-linux/

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28546217/mcrypt-is-missing-from-your-system-os-yosemite

Comment: Thanks you. It work for me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i fix this by other way:

**$ brew tap homebrew/php**

Then:

**$ brew install php54-mcrypt**

if get:

*Error*: Formulae found in multiple taps:

- homebrew/php/php54
- josegonzalez/php/php54

Just use: **$ brew untap josegonzalez/php**

Reason: josegonzalez/php moved to homebrew/php.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The best thing that I can recommend is using Laravel Homestead. It's the best way that I have found to get your thing working. It's as easy as drinking a cup of cold coffee. Homestead comes in with a lots of stuff like:

- Ubuntu 14.04
- PHP 5.6
- HHVM
- Nginx
- MySQL
- Postgres
- Node (With PM2, Bower, Grunt, and Gulp)
- Redis
- Memcached
- Beanstalkd
- Laravel Envoy
- Blackfire Profiler

And plus you can deploy multiple PHP Sites without managing anything like this.

Link: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/homestead